# How to protect the common ground on a voltage divider

Tags: microcontroller, diodes, stm32, voltage-divider, short-circuit

I have a voltage divider who looks like the following:

[image: Voltage divider schematic]

This voltage divider is linked to an [STM32MP1 Development Kit](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32mp157a-dk1.html#overview)

By inadvertance we made a short circuit in another place of the circuit that made almost every components to fry... I'm convinced that the common ground here is the issue but i can't find any documentation on how i can prevent this issue on the future circuits.

Do i need to isolate ground with some electric transformer?

Can i protect high voltage to go on the common ground with some diode tricks?

Comment: You made a short elsewhere, but asking us about some unrelated part of the circuit?

Comment: In general, you can't prevent damage to the board and parts by arbitrary incorrect voltages. You can prevent specific problems, though. Was the short circuit problem from an input cable being connected wrong? You could add protection on all of the inputs that could break the connection before damaging more of the circuit.

Comment: I would strongly advise you to get some **hard evidence** that the common ground is really the issue. You could add all the protections possible and still not do anything about the actual design fault, then adding the protections is rather pointless.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I can't post the whole schema here...

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie all the other ships that are on this ground where fried too... I have no other idea about what is the problem...

Comment: *I can't post the whole schema here* Then we can't help you. I suggest getting someone with more experience in electronics to look at your setup to see what is wrong.

Comment: Not enough information to draw any conclusion.

Comment: `I'm convinced that the common ground here is the issue` ... unconvince yourself and then proceed to prove it

Comment: @jsotola How can i prove it? I'm new to electronics so i have a lot to learn... The issue here is that my coworker made a short circuit and the STM board was not working anymore after that but we have no clue what happened... And that is the only place where the high voltage circuit is linked to the data circuit....

Answer (score -3):

If you're seeking a good voltage isolator for testing your circuit, I suggest an optoisolater between IC and divider. It's possible your capacitor is behaving strangely; tried changing values, or adding one on the input. As others have stated, I'd check for continuity between resistors (with cap out of circuit).